# sklearn random state not random

Tags: python, random, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have been playing around with the random state variable from [StratifiedKFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) in sklearn, but it does not seem to be random. I believe that setting `random_state=5`, should give me a different testing set then setting `random_state=4`, but this does not seem to be the case. I have created some crude reproducible code below. First I load my data:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
```

Then I set `random_state=5`, for which I store the last values:

```
skf=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5,random_state=5)
for (train, test) in skf.split(X,y): full_test_1=test
full_test_1

array([ 40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  90,  91,  92,
        93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145,
       146, 147, 148, 149])
```

Doing the same procedure for `random_state=4`:

```
skf=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5,random_state=4)
for (train, test) in skf.split(X,y): full_test_2=test
full_test_2

array([ 40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  90,  91,  92,
        93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145,
       146, 147, 148, 149])
```

I can then check that they are equal:

```
np.array_equal(full_test_1,full_test_2)
True
```

I do not think that the two random states should be returning the same numbers. Is there a flaw in my logic or code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the linked docs

> random_state : None, int or RandomState
>
> **When shuffle=True**, pseudo-random number generator state used for shuffling. If None, use default numpy RNG for shuffling.

You aren't setting shuffle=True in your call to StratifiedKFold, so random_state won't do anything.